# Activity resets on Fragment Transaction

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity that loads multiple fragments depending on user action (button click) or event (FCM Data Message which triggers a LocalBroadcast).

I hit a snag recently when I put a Fragment Transaction inside a BroadcastReceiver, and as soon as the receiver gets triggered, instead of loading up the next fragment, I get the first (default) fragment which is loaded in the OnCreate of the activity, implying that the Activity has reset/restarted somehow.

Given the speed of this, the only error I managed to see before the logcat on Android Studio reset was this :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after
>   onSaveInstanceState

Digging around hasn't helped much, [except for this article on Activity State Loss](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) which I discovered. It is rather old (2013) but seems to make sense. However, there is no solution that I can think of, short of making my fragment a bit more complicated, and handing the next fragment's logic in this one itself.

Please find the bit of code where this happens below.

```
BroadcastReceiver assistanceReceivedStatusReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void dummyfunc(){
            return;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // this is triggered by the localBroadcast from FCM Service
            boolean requestresult = intent.getBooleanExtra("success", true);
            if(!requestresult) {
                // we don't have a responder
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: =======================================");
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: =======================================");
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: UNABLE TO FIND A RESPONDER");
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: =======================================");
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: =======================================");
                String message = "Unable to find you a responder, please try again!";
                frameAnimation.stop();
                txtRequestStatus.setText(message);
                dialogButtonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                showBottomAppBar();
                showMenuFab();
                moveMenuRight();
                setMenuImage(R.drawable.baseline_undo_white_24dp);
                menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        dialogLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        waitingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        moveMenuCenter();
                        resetMenuImage();
                        menuButton.setOnClickListener(defaultMenuButtonListener);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                // we have a responder
                // this is a one time receiver - set up an Observable for the Live<Incident>
                // and unregister self.
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: =======================================");
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: =======================================");
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: RECEIVED A RESPONDER");
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: =======================================");
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: =======================================");
                inIncident = true;
                Bundle nextbundle = new Bundle();
                responderinfo = intent.getBundleExtra("responderinfo");
                nextbundle.putParcelable("data", intent.getBundleExtra("data"));
                nextbundle.putBundle("responderinfo", responderinfo);
                // GO! GO! GO!!!
                //startFragmentWithArgs(new RequestAssistFragmentDeliver(),nextbundle );
                RequestAssistFragmentDeliver deliver = new RequestAssistFragmentDeliver();
                deliver.setArguments(nextbundle);
                ((Reviv) getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.containerFrameLayout, deliver).commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        }
    };
```

Any ideas on what's going wrong? As always, I'm happy to share more info based on what is needed (the code base is humongous, and knowing what is needed helps me share the relevant segments).

**UPDATE 1 :**
Sharing the functions as requested by Udit. These are wrapper functions, to help make the code a little more readable. The bottomAppBar (BottomAppBar) and menuButton (FAB) are views that are loaded in the Activity, and I make associations in each Fragment by calling a getter defined in the Activity.

```
(MainActivity)getActivity.getBottomAppBar();
```

Functions:

```
private void showBottomAppBar(){
        bottomAppBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        menuButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void moveMenuRight(){
        bottomAppBar.setFabAlignmentMode(BottomAppBar.FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_END);
    }

    private void showMenuFab(){
        //bottomAppBar.setFabAttached(true);
        menuButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: can you share these 3 methods: showBottomAppBar();
                showMenuFab();
                moveMenuRight();

Comment: @Udit : Updated the question with the information you needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can figure out, your activity is restarting because of the crash while adding the fragment (java.lang.IllegalStateException).

To confirm, you can replace

```
.commit()
```

method with

```
.commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

and see if this solves your problem

Comment: I have already used that in code and still get the crash (Its in my code segment above). Is there any way the crash can be avoided or handled?

Comment: can you share the complete crash logs? adb logs can be saved to a file using command: adb logcat -d > logcat.txt.

Comment: I tried looking for the logs which had the message but was unable to - the activity restarts and AS just resets the logs, and I was unable to duplicate this error message. (Pinky swear, I saw it the first time) 

However the behavior persists - the logs are at
  
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_zd7SM1kPZ4R_6QrHzh1QZOr7hc5VQdH/view?usp=sharing

I have annotated the approximate point at which the activity restart is triggered. I have also decided to pursue a different way to handle this issue, so I am accepting your answer as that is the 'prescribed' way to handle the error.